# No "Manage" button in Storage for my boot drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I have two drives on my machine, Fast, the original 256GB SSD in my MP2013, and Bigger, a USB-attached 2TB drive.

I'm trying to download XCode 10.2, but it complains there is not enough room on my drive. There is no way to download to any drive other than Fast using the App Store and there is no XIF available (yet?).

Fast has 27 GB free, but much of this is "Purgable". According to Apple's dox, I should use About this Mac... Storage... Manage... to remove this. However, as you can see, I have no Manage button.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: Try launching the Storage Management.app directly via Spotlight or by running `open -a "Storage Management.app"`.